# error: Expect ")" before CLLocation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got this error:

> Expect ")" before CLLocation

My code:

```
MyAppDelegate.h

@protocol AskerConnectionDelegate
-(void) postNewQuestionForUserID: (NSString*)uID Text: (NSString*)text location: (CLLocation*)loc; 

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

You should import the necessary header files.

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
```

Or just add a *@class* directive before the *@protocol* declaration,

```
@class CLLocation;
```

Adding a *@class* directive just lets the compiler know that the particular class exists without having to import the header file.

Comment: He should also switch to using `clang`, which would have provided a better error message.